# Outlook calendar request shows as plain mail in Apple Mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, apple-mail, calendar

When I receive a meeting request from another Outlook client I can see it as a meeting request in my Outlook email program on my PC. I can then enter the calendar reservation automatically.

The same message shows up as a plain email with no meeting information in Apple Mail on my Mac. The body of the message is preserved, but the meeting schedule attachment is not visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok... I found an application called "Letter Opener Pro" that integrates with Apple Mail and makes the Outlook calendar requests show up as normal ics files. These can then be added to Apple's iCal. So far it works great!

Comment: Great you could solve it, could you add your comment above as an answer and mark the question as answered? (See end of first FAQ question http://superuser.com/faq#questions.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip- I don't post here very often (ever)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... To answer my own question, I found an application called "Letter Opener Pro" that integrates with Apple Mail and makes the Outlook calendar requests show up as normal ics email attachments. These can then be added to Apple's Calendar. So far it works great!